# Using .on("hashchange", ...) to trigger page changes in a single page application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, web

I was wondering if it is bad practice to use something like

```
window.location.hash = '#example';
```

and having this:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    if (window.location.hash) {
        navigateToHashUrl(window.location.hash);
    }
});

function navigateToHashUrl(hashUrl) {
    if(hashUrl == '#example') {
        goToExamplePage();
    } else if ...
    ...
}
```

to delegate to the actual methods that will use $().load('html') to load the page?

In some cases in my web-app, the front end will send a request, and if everything is OK, the back end will respond with data that indicates to change the hash url. In those cases, I use this kind of thing.

I don't see why it would be bad practice, but I am new to web-dev and would like to know if I am doing anything that I shouldn't be doing.

Thanks!

Comment: Although I don't see anything wrong with this approach it might benefit you to use a router plugin: https://github.com/camme/jquery-router-plugin

Comment: Daniel, could you expand on what goToExamplePage() is doing?

Answer (score 0):

The real benefit of a single page application (spa) is to dynamically change portions of the screen based on interaction with the user. Constraining yourself to having the backend server app manage the page transitions seems limiting.

Most recent spa's I have developed bootstrap the html once and after that the client-side application drives the process, requesting data as needed based on user interaction.

You can do what you are doing, but I agree with comments that suggest you might be better off using a router to facilitate.

Personally, I would try to move away from a 'page' mindset and use the backend to serve up data through a RESTful api. After all, that is why it is called a SINGLE page application.